# Android with ActionBar Sherlock. ImageButton does not get onClick event

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I have an Android app that uses ActionBar Sherlock. I create a menu that has an ImageButton whose state is defined in a drawable resource file. (All of them pasted below).

Although I am able to toggle the selected / not selected states of the ImageButton the click listener does not seem to fire.

When the activity is created I inflate the menu, I get the ImageButton and I register the event listener. I debugged and it all seems ok (I am registering the event on the correct ImageButton).

What do you think could cause the ImageButton to not get the onClick callback?

Cheers....

here's some code:

menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
          android:showAsAction="always|withText"           
          android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_my_activity"
          />     
</menu>
```

the menu_my_activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/button_with_states"
        android:clickable="true" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

and the registering of the listener:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = (MenuInflater) this.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_watchlist, menu);
    menu.getItem(0).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.imageButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Log.d("Test", "Hello");   
    }
        });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: try making the ImageView unclickable (set the attribute to false). does that help?

Comment: even if it does work for you... you should still use `onOptionsItemSelected()` as David Caunt suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my suggested fix. There really isn't any need for a separate actionLayout since the result you want is pretty simple as it is. Note that we don't need to create an "ImageView" for the ActionBar... the `android:icon` attribute sets that up for us. Use `android:title` to set the icon's text.

menu_watchlist.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/image_button"
          android:showAsAction="always|withText"           
          android:title="title"
          android:icon="@drawable/button_with_states" />     
</menu>
```

setup options menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_watchlist, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.image_button:
            Log.d("Test", "Hello");
            break; 
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 1):

When you press on an ActionView, in ABS or the native system ActionBar, the [onOptionsItemSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29) method is called. You don't need to manually attach an event listener, and indeed this approach will **not** work consistently.

To listen for ActionItem selection:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_save:
            //Save was pressed, call a method
            break;
        case R.id.menu_another_item:
            //A different item was pressed
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The use of onOptionsItemSelected is a little counter-intuitive but hails back to the days of using Menus, as does onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is useful but didn't really solve the problem. Alex's suggestion to use the android:icon was just what I needed.

Comment: AFAICT (as of Oct 2012), if you are setting a custom layout for a menu item then you must also explicitly attach an event listener. onOptionItemSelected does not fire automatically for clicks on the new view.

Comment: @david caunt case R.id.menu_save: gives me a compile time error: case expression must be constant